# How do I fix bad credential error in django

Tags: django

I have created a contact form that is suppose to send that message via email as well as maintain those messages in database.
I have added the following in settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

And the following code in views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        desc = request.POST.get("desc")
        instance = Contact(name=name, email=email, desc=desc)
        instance.save()

        desc = request.POST['desc']
        send_mail('Contact Form',
            desc,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['********@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False)
```

Its not giving any errors in command prompt. However its giving the following error when I am submitting the form

SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s1sm259896wrv.97 - gsmtp')

Answer (score 0):

Google now doesn’t accept login from less secure apps. So you need to go to https://myaccount.google.com/security. Turn ON “Allow less secure apps".